# boost asio exire_at not triggering

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I tried to get following boost asio example to run but anyhow the expire_at function don't call my callback. If I replace the ptime object with plain seconds it works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

void callback(const boost::system::error_code& e) {
    std::cout << "callback: " << e << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {

    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service, boost::posix_time::time_from_string("2020-03-14 23:44:12.000"));
    timer.async_wait(callback);
    io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not specifying the timezone.

For example I'm in a +2 timezone.

Assuming the current time is: "2020-03-14 23:44:10.000", given that format, I wound need to set the value to 2020-03-14 21:44:12.000 . for it to trigger in 2 seconds. Or update the format and specify the timezone.

Tip: Set the date in the past and you should see the callback trigger immediately.